# When do we use typescript import * as?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

Trying to developer a mental model for what `import * as Blah` does.  For example:

```
import * as StackTrace from 'stacktrace-js';
```

How does that work and when do we do `import *`?

Comment: This is more of a JS thing than a typescript thing.
Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: _when do we do import *_: not really ever in production.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not really an answer, but a usage: Consider you have a few constant strings to be used in your application, you can define them in a single file and export

```
export const name = "NAME";
export const someOtherString = "SOME_CONST_STRING";
```

Then you can import them in a single variable using:

```
import * as CONST_STRINGS from './yourFilePath';
```

and use as

```
CONST_STRINGS.name 
CONST_STRINGS.someOtherString
```

Comment: How is this different than exporting an object containing all the strings as a default export? Or, better question, why would you use this instead?

Comment: @Nathan an object containing the strings cannot be treeshaked, individual strings can be `treeshaked`. If you add 1000 strings in the object, all of them are available in the compiled code, even if you're using only few of them.

Comment: So in this instance `CONST_STRINGS.foo` would be tree shaken if it was never used, even if `CONST_STRING.bar` was used? Presumably `CONST_STRINGS` is an `object` type, so what allows it to be treeshaken when other object (imported default objects) can't be? (Thanks for your answer btw, very interesting stuff!)

Answer (score 12):

From the [TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-the-entire-module-into-a-single-variable-and-use-it-to-access-the-module-exports):

> Import the entire module into a single variable, and use it to access the module exports

---

The example code  imports *all exports* of the `stacktrace-js` module into a variable called `StackTrace`.

Any *named exports* will be available as properties of the same name.

If the module has a *default export* it will be available as the `default` property.

---

Note also from the [TypeScript Module doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has a concept of modules. TypeScript shares this concept.

So TypeScript modules behave in the same way as ES6 JavaScript modules.

---

You would use `import * as` in either TypeScript or JavaScript when you want access to all of the module exports in a single variable.