# Using assert in Typescript and getting 'Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation' error

Tags: node.js, typescript, assert

I'm new to Typescript and I can't find any useful way to resolve this error:

```
error TS2775: Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.
```

I'm using a simple enough use case

```js
import * as assert from 'assert'
import someFunction from './someFunction.js'

function test() {
  assert.strict.equal(someFunction(1, 1), 2)
}

test()
```

I've tried adding `/** @type {any} */` on top of the file, but I'm still seeing this error. I'd love any advice about what I could do to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this library should be imported via `import *`. It works as you expect if you just:

```
import assert from 'assert'
```

`import * as Foo from 'foo'` will wrap all named exports into a single object, where `import Foo from 'foo'` will just take the default export. Which to use depends on how the code you're importing is structured. But, in general, it's best to start with `import Foo from 'foo'` unless the documention tells you otherwise.

[See working example on the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwM5IKazgMyhEcDkyas+AUKZgK4B2AxjMBNXErqgGI32PUAUCALjjVKIAEboANHDFCR49AEo4Ab1JwNcKKhiUozBHADUM0gF9yVOgyZwYqJDF7K1GouhgA6R1GD1PqACOlAgANrysIBxcNnwAjNJxitIATIrm5PaOzkA)

More info: [When do we use typescript import * as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055956/when-do-we-use-typescript-import-as)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much, your help is much appreciated!